# What events should I handle in express response (stream) object to handle when the response finishes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, dom-events, node-streams

I'm trying to automatically log when a request finishes.

I have something like this:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    var startTime = clock.now();
    res.on('end'. function() {
        logger.trace("END ...", req.path, res.statusCode, clock.now() - startTime, ...);
    });
    res.on('error'. function() {
        logger.trace("END ...", req.path, clock.now() - startTime, ...);
    });
    nest();
}
```

- Does doing that cover all the cases? (e.g. when a request get's interrupted)
- Will I be called at most once for every request?

If any of the answers is no, please include how to do it.

Comment: Is this package not good enough for your use case? https://github.com/expressjs/response-time

Comment: It's not. It just set's a response header with the time. I want to be able to log when a request ends. __That includes when it's interrupted by the client__. The module you mentioned uses `on-headers`, which decorated the `res.writeHead` function. The onHeaders function should not get called on interrupted requests. @1461269 @arjabbar

Answer (score 2):

Try setting up finish event according to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_finish):

Here is a sample implementation:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.on('finish', function() {
        console.log('the response has been sent', res.statusCode);
    });
    next();
});
```